# Given an exact formula, how can Mathematica find a probability distribution whose PDF matches it?

Tags: probability-or-statistics, distributions, expression-manipulation

So, given some data, *Mathematica* 10.2 can now attempt to figure out what probability distribution might have produced it. Cool! But suppose that, instead of having data, we have something that is in some ways better -- a formula. Let's call it $f$. We suspect -- perhaps because $f$ is non-negative over some domain and because the integral of $f$ over that domain is 1 --  that $f$ is actually the PDF of some distribution (Normal, Lognormal, Gamma, Weibull, etc.) or some relatively simple transform of that distribution.

Is there any way that *Mathematica* can help figure out the distribution (or simple transform) whose PDF is the same as $f$?

Example: Consider the following formula:

```
1/(2*E^((-m + Log[5])^2/8)*Sqrt[2*Pi])
```

$$\frac{e^{-\frac{1}{8} (\log (5)-m)^2}}{2 \sqrt{2 \pi }}$$

As it happens -- and as I discovered with some research and guesswork -- this formula is the PDF of `NormalDistribution[Log[5], 2]` evaluated at $m$. But is there a better way than staring or guessing to discover this fact?  That is, help me write `FindExactDistribution[f_, params_]`.

### Notes

- The motivation for the problem comes from thinking about Conjugate Prior distributions but I suspect it might have a more general application.
- One could start with mapping PDF evaluated at $m$ over a variety of continuous distributions.  And if I did this I would at some point get to what I will call $g$, which is the PDF or the `NormalDistribution` with parameters $a$ and $b$ evaluated at $m$.

  1/(b*E^((-a + m)^2/(2*b^2))*Sqrt[2*Pi])

$$\frac{e^{-\frac{(m-a)^2}{2 b^2}}}{\sqrt{2 \pi } b}$$

But unless I knew that if I replaced $a$ by `Log[5]` and $b$ by $2$ that I would get $f$, this fact would not mean a lot to me. I suppose I could look at the `TreeForm` of $f$ and $g$ and I would notice certain similarities, and that might be a hint, but I am not sure how to make much progress beyond that observation. Ultimately, the problem looks to be about finding substitutions in parts of a tree ($g$) which, after evaluation, yield a tree that matches a target $f$. I have the suspicion that this is a difficult problem with an NKS flavor but one for which *Mathematica* and its ability to transform expressions might be well suited.

---

I appreciate the responses here.  But let me provide an example that is perhaps not so easy.  Suppose the target function *f* is as follows: $\frac{7}{10 (a-2)^2}$ for the domain ($-\infty,\frac{13}{10}$].  If we create a probability distribution out of this and then generate 10,000 random samples from the distribution and then run FindDistribution

```
 dis = ProbabilityDistribution[7/(10 (-2 + a)^2), {a, -\[Infinity], 13/10}];
 rv = RandomVariate[dis,10^4];
 fd=FindDistribution[rv,5]
```

The result is a mixture distribution of normal distributions, a beta distribution, a weibull distribution, a normal distribution and a mixture distribution of a normal distribution and a gamma distribution.

The mixture distributions are clearly of the wrong form, the normal distribution is clearly not right, Although I am not positive, I don't believe the Weibull Distribution or the Beta Distribution is correct either.  In fact, I don't know what the correct answer is, though I think it might be a fairly simple transform of a single parameter distribution.  The point, however, is that the FindDistribution process, does not seem to work in this case.  And that's why I am hoping for something better.

Comment: What if you sampled (with a random number generator) from `f` assuming that it *is* a pdf, then used the resulting data in Mathematica to see if it will find a pdf that matches the data?

Comment: Given that the software seems poised to implement almost every distribution there is, one would hope there is a way to find the closest-match among built-ins…

Comment: > "In fact, I don't know what the correct answer is,"  .... ///////////// I like your new example. It is the pdf of $Y = 2-X$ where $X \sim Pareto(1, 7/10)$. Not sure it would be easy to do that automagically, however.

Comment: There are infinitely many distributions ... (and thus also infinitely many possible matches)

Comment: ... which really highlights the difficulty of providing a general solution to such problems. The number of named special distributions is tiny compared to the number of common functional forms .. and even if one just wishes to restrict focus on named cases, how does one deal with $X^2$ or ratios of common forms, or truncated or censored functions of common forms, or shifted cases, or ...

Answer (score 13):

**UPDATE:** quite interesting parallel discussion and solutions (see Emerson Willard answer) can be found [**HERE**](http://community.wolfram.com/groups/-/m/t/546818).

---

Maybe this is not exactly what you are looking for, but at least this gives you a very close guess and it is easy to figure out the rest.

```
dis = ProbabilityDistribution[
   1/(2*E^((-m + Log[5])^2/8)*Sqrt[2*Pi]), {m, -Infinity, Infinity}];

PDF[dis, m] // TraditionalForm
```

[image]

Generate data:

```
data = RandomVariate[dis, 10^4];
```

Match:

```
FindDistribution[data]
```

> NormalDistribution[1.60001, 1.97652]

Check:

```
Log[5] // N
```

> 1.6094379124341003

So you did not get symbolic Log[5] but at least you got distribution right. This will work in much more complicated cases.

- **Possible continuous distributions** for TargetFunctions are: BetaDistribution, CauchyDistribution, ChiDistribution, ChiSquareDistribution, ExponentialDistribution, ExtremeValueDistribution, FrechetDistribution, GammaDistribution, GumbelDistribution, HalfNormalDistribution, InverseGaussianDistribution, LaplaceDistribution, LevyDistribution, LogisticDistribution, LogNormalDistribution, MaxwellDistribution, NormalDistribution, ParetoDistribution, RayleighDistribution, StudentTDistribution, UniformDistribution, WeibullDistribution.
- **Possible discrete distributions** for TargetFunctions are: BenfordDistribution, BinomialDistribution, BorelTannerDistribution, DiscreteUniformDistribution, GeometricDistribution, LogSeriesDistribution, NegativeBinomialDistribution, PascalDistribution, PoissonDistribution, WaringYuleDistribution, ZipfDistribution.

Answer (score 12):

```
f[m_] = 1/(2*E^((-m + Log[5])^2/8)*Sqrt[2*Pi]);

Integrate[f[m], {m, -Infinity, Infinity}]
```

> 1

```
dist = ProbabilityDistribution[f[m], {m, -Infinity, Infinity}];
```

Since the integral of f[m] is unity, f[m] does not have to be scaled to be a distribution. A candidate distribution will probably have two parameters and must be defined on the interval {-Infinity, Infinity}. The built-in distributions with two parameters and defined on the interval {-Infinity, Infinity} are

```
distributions = ToExpression /@ Names["*Distribution"];

twoParamDist = Select[distributions,
    FreeQ[PDF[#[a, b], x], #] &&
      DistributionDomain[#[a, b]] === Interval[{-Infinity, Infinity}] &] // 
   Quiet;
```

The target PDF for comparison is

```
PDF[dist, m]
```

[image]

Comparing this PDF with the form of those of the built-in two-parameter distributions will greatly limit the candidates

```
({#, PDF[#[a, b], m]} & /@ twoParamDist) // 
  Prepend[#, {Distribution, PDF}] & //
 Grid[#, Frame -> All] &
```

[image]

The NormalDistribution is the likely distribution

```
dist2 = NormalDistribution[a, b];

param = Solve[{Mean[dist2] == Mean[dist],
   Variance[dist2] == Variance[dist],
   DistributionParameterAssumptions[dist2]}, {a, b}]
```

> {{a -> Log[5], b -> 2}}

Verifying that the PDFs are identical

```
PDF[dist2 /. param[[1]], m] == PDF[dist, m] // Simplify
```

> True

So the target distribution is

```
dist2 /. param[[1]]
```

> NormalDistribution[Log[5], 2]

Comment: This ought to catch the two-parameter distributions: `Select[Names["*Distribution"], (Length["ArgumentsPattern" /. SyntaxInformation[ToExpression[#]]] == 2) &]`. After that, you can do further filtering with `DistributionDomain[]`.

Comment: @J.M. - Your recommendation includes the `LandauDistribution`. Unfortunately, the PDF for that distribution does not evaluate symbolically. I do not want to have to figure out some kind of workaround for that. Also, similar problem might arise with other distributions when the number of arguments isn't two.

Comment: "Unfortunately, the PDF for that distribution does not evaluate symbolically." - I guess there ought to be a check that the head of the result is not `PDF[]`, but it will admittedly start to look clumsy at that point…

Comment: @J.M.- that is essentially what `FreeQ[PDF[#[a, b], x], #] ` does. If the PDF doesn't evaluate then the distribution name is still present.

Comment: There are parts of this answer that I like but I think you are using a bit too much human intelligence ;)  Yes, once you say that the formula comes from a normal distribution it is not too hard to figure out which normal distribution.  But what if the target distribution is not normal and you really don't know what it is.  Then what? What similarity metric are you using between the expression for the PDFs and the expression for the target distribution?

Comment: @SethChandler - The primary purpose is to automatically narrow the candidate distributions from 144 (built-in) to a limited set (13) and display their PDFs for comparison. You can then manageably review the forms for viable candidates. If, as here, there is a match of the form then it is fairly easy to find the parameters. If there were no direct match, then the problem would become more complicated. First step then might be to check three-parameter distributions for a match of forms. Failing an obvious match then use `DistributionFitTest` with the various candidates.