# Recognise probability distribution

Tags: probability-or-statistics

Given a PDF, can Mathematica tell me the name of a distribution?  The obvious

```
ProbabilityDistribution[Exp[-x], {x, 0, ∞}]
```

does not evaluate usefully.

What I'm really interested in is

```
ProbabilityDistribution[(2 x)/(1 + x^2)^2, {x, 0, ∞}]
```

which is the ratio of two `RayleighDistribution` variables?

If I know the name for a distribution, an Internet search may reveal some relevant properties of the distribution.

Comment: Related: [Given an exact formula, how can Mathematica find a probability distribution whose PDF matches it?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/91408/given-an-exact-formula-how-can-mathematica-find-a-probability-distribution-whos)